# OpenLayers 3 how can I create an ol.geom.Polygon from an array of ol.geom.Point features

Tags: openlayers-3

I see that it is possible to pass in an array of ol.coordinate elements but I don't see an obvious way to pass in an array of ol.geom.Point features. What is the most efficient way to create a polygon from an array of point features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop in all your points to collect their geometry, then create your polygon from that collection.

```
var coordinates = [];
points.forEach(function(point) {
  coodinates.push(point.getCoordinates());
});
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([coordinates]);
```